# Building an SSIS 2008 solution using TFS 2008

Tags: ssis, continuous-integration

I am trying to build an SSIS 2008 solution using TFS 2008. I created a 'TFSBuild.proj' file using the build definition wizard. My build appears to work, but fails at the final step with the error...

> (0,0): warning MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Release|Any CPU" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.

I've tried...

1. Leaving the 'FlavorToBuild' & 'PlatformToBuild' values blank in the 'TFSBuild.proj'
2. Amend the 'FlavorToBuild' & 'PlatformToBuild' values in the 'TFSBuild.proj' file to various other strings

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems related: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/b67425a4-2805-4d77-9b9c-3d1484583971

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can't build SSIS project files, out of the box, because they are not in MSBuild format. Great!! - Sarcasm overload.